# Before callback, how to use?

Tags: papaparse

I am looking for help to understand how to use the before callback of Papaparse parser.
In the doc, it is written:

> before is an optional callback that lets you inspect each file before
>   parsing begins. Return an object like:

```
{
action: "abort",
reason: "Some reason",
config: // altered config...
}
```

> to alter the flow of parsing. Actions can be "abort" to skip this and
>   all other files in the queue, "skip" to skip just this file, or
>   "continue" to carry on (equivalent to returning nothing). reason can
>   be a reason for aborting. config can be a modified configuration for
>   parsing just this file.

Before callback arguments are '*file*' and '*inputElem*'.

What I want to do is check on the db if there is a collection in which '*name*' is equal to *file.name.slice(0,-4)* (file's name without ext.). If there is, skip the file and console.log the skipping.
It looks easy, but I don't know how to use the returned object! :(

Can you drive me a bit?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
if (file.name.slice(0,-4) == name) {
    console.log("Skipping", name);
    return { action: "skip" };
}
```

Comment: I tried this:
`// Callbacks
  before: function(file, inputElem) {
    if (Datasets.find({name: file.name.slice(0,-4)}).count() !== 0) {
      return {
         action: "skip",
         reason: "This dataset already exists."
     };
  }
}`

It does not work... :(